# UPS shuts down when using with modem alone

Tags: laptop, power-supply, ups, dsl-modem

I'm in a place where power cuts are very common for around 5 hours a day. I have a DSL internet connection and a PC. I recently purchased a new laptop which easily gives me 4 hours of battery backup.

So, if power goes off, the ADSL modem goes off and I'm no longer online. The ADSL wifi modem only needs very little DC power through an AC to DC adapter.

I want to be online with laptop and small power supply for modem. 
So, i purchased this INTEX UPS which has 12V 7.5A-H lead acid battery. My idea was to use this UPS with modem alone so I can easily have 4 hours of power supply to modem. But when I use it with DSL modem alone, the UPS only works for 5 minutes and then shuts down. It is not that the UPS bettery is nill, but may be it is due to UPS thinking that there is no output device due to very low power need of modem.

If i use the UPS with PC, it gives the regular 10-15 minutes backup. How can i use the UPS with modem alone?

What is the minimum output wattage required for the UPS to not shut down.

Comment: I would design a UPS to shut down on power input and not on power output.

Comment: What type ADSL and what are the V and A on it.

Comment: teracom ADSL2+ wifi modem. It needs 12V 500mA DC power.

Comment: So you have a 90 Watt UPS. You could add a car bulb (lets say 10 Watts).

Comment: hmmm.... so fully charged UPS will run for <15 minutes maximum with ADSL connected? or did i fail the math.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Math says it should power that modem for about 15 hours, minus the losses to convert power. So at least 14 hours.

Comment: @Buscar You got it wrong. If i use the ups with desktop PC it gives 10-15min. What should be the minimum wattage of output devices connected? Now i see on the ups manual that it has NO LOAD AUTO SHUTDOWN function which should be making it shutdown.

Comment: I did get it wrong, it is hours not minutes. So my suggestion with using the car light bulb still stands, you will need light anyway.

Comment: +1 Many UPS systems have a "feature" to shut off if power output is below a certain level (e.g. mine, APC, shuts off below 15 watts). It's infuriating. Some UPS systems can be connected by USB to a computer to change these settings, but most can't. I think they're designed by people who only think about ineffecient energy-guzzling devices and who assume that low power must mean it's on standby. I've been looking for a way to kill this stupid "feature" but I can't find anything.